# Using recoil state management synchronously

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, react-state-management, recoiljs

I am trying to update states using recoil state management.
Here is the relevant code:

```js
const Done = (props) => {

  const [fullAdState, setFullAddresses]: any = useRecoilState(fullAddressesStateAtom)
  const [sentAdState, setSentAdState]= useRecoilState(addressesSentStateAtom)
  const [updatedAddresses, setUpdatedAddresses] = useRecoilState(fullAddressesStateAtom)

  const setSentAddresses = () => {
    setFullAddresses([...fullAdState].map((adrs, i) => {
        return adrs.checked ? {...adrs, sent: true}: adrs
      }))
      setSentAdState([...sentAdState].map((val,idx) => {
        return fullAdState[idx].checked? true : val
      }))     
}
const updateAddresses = () => {
  const arr = []
  fullAdState.map((adrs, idx) => {
    if (!sentAdState[idx]){
      arr.push(adrs)    
    }
  })
  setUpdatedAddresses(arr)
}

  useEffect(() => {
  setSentAddresses();
  updateAddresses();

  },[])

return (
        <div dir="rtl">
         ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

In the useEffect part, im calling to setSentAddresses that sets two state, one after another (first fullAdState and then sentAdState.
After that, im calling to updateAddresses that should update updatedAddresses according to the data in fullAdState and sentAdState (that should get the updated data at the first part).

Because of the way recoil set state works, both fullAdState and sentAdState got their new data asynchronously to the entire component (or at least the entire useEffect part) and so the data in it is not updated when im trying to read it for updating updatedAddresses.

Im sure there is a normal way to do it. Is there someone that knows how and can help?

Because of the way recoil set state works, both fullAdState and sentAdState got their new data asynchronously to the entire component (or at least the entire useEffect part) and so the data in it is not updated when im trying to read it for updating updatedAddresses.

Im sure there is a normal way to do it. Is there someone that knows how and can help?

Comment: What are you doing with all these states? The entire code seems so redundant, everything can easily be derived from `fullAdState`. Like `const sentAdState = fullAdState.map(item => item.sent); const updatedAddresses = fullAdState.filter(item => item.sent);` although I'm not even sure if you need `sentAdState` besides to create `updatedAddresses`.

Comment: How do you know I don’t need these states. My project contains other more components with some different goals. These states get updated on different situations and that’s why I need them separately.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed!
I added one more “useEffect” function that calls to “updateAddresses” (instead of in the first “useEffect”).
I defined this “useEffect” dependency to be “[sentAdState]”.
Now, the first “useEffect” runs and calls to “setSentAddresses” to update the relevant state. Then the “sentAdState” is getting updated and therefore the other “useEffect” runs and calls to r that